# Where put custom library in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, custom-component, directory-structure

I have custom library on my project.

At now i storage that library in vendor folder.

But i think that is not good, because vendor is folder for third-party developers and vendor folder was marked as gitignore

Where i should put custom library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory almost anywhere you want, I created a folder called "lib" at the same level as your module and vendor folders to put custom libraries inside of.

Don't forget to add the namespace to your autoloader!